# Why negative values appear sporadically in Fibonacci Series' calculation?

Tags: c++, fibonacci, integer-overflow

I have coded a program which calculates Fibonacci Series in C++. Here's the code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of terms: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Fibonacci Series: ";

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        // Prints the first two terms.
        if(i == 1) {
            cout << t1 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        if(i == 2) {
            cout << t2 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = nextTerm;

        cout << nextTerm << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I give input `n = 100`, the list grows. And there appears some negative number.

I know it happens because of the data type value limit. But my question is **why some of the are negative and some has positive value**.
Like
`-285007387, -945834654, -1230842041, 2118290601, 887448560, -1289228135, -401779575, -1691007710,` 
this is an example from the middle somewhere in the output.

```
Enter the number of terms: 100
Fibonacci Series: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, -1323752223, 512559680, -811192543, -298632863, -1109825406, -1408458269, 1776683621, 368225352, 2144908973, -1781832971, 363076002, -1418756969, -1055680967, 1820529360, 764848393, -1709589543, -944741150, 1640636603, 695895453, -1958435240, -1262539787, 1073992269, -188547518, 885444751, 696897233, 1582341984, -2015728079, -433386095, 1845853122, 1412467027, -1036647147, 375819880, -660827267, -285007387, -945834654, -1230842041, 2118290601, 887448560, -1289228135, -401779575, -1691007710, -2092787285, 511172301, -1581614984, -1070442683, 1642909629, 572466946, -2079590721, -1507123775, 708252800, -798870975, -90618175, -889489150, 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Integers have limited range. When signed integers overflow, and their highest bit ends up being set, you will get some negative number instead. You might fare better with `unsigned long long` as type instead of `int`, and even better with an arbitrary precision library.

Comment: Why are you using int in the first place? It probably is better to use `std::uint64_t` since all Fibonacci numbers are unsigned anyway, but what you are seeing is integer overflow the values just become too big to be represented by your integer type. (32 bits I think)

Comment: *"because of the data type limit"* -- You've answered your own question. Why do you think hitting this limit can only explain sign changes from positive to negative?

Comment: The advice by @tobi_s is good but even with 64-bit unsigned integers, you wont go any higher than `fibonacci(93)`. To go any higher, you need a big integer library. Many exists out there; this [one](https://github.com/AtmoFX/bigint/blob/master/source/bigint.h) (which is actually mine) has an implementation of Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Atmo sure, I think my post was clear about that. With gcc's `__uint128_t` extension one can go all the way to fib(185). BTW If one doesn't care about the lowest digits, one can also evaluate the sequence using the closed-form expressions and floating-point math.

Comment: @tobi_s Oh you mean that formula with the golden ratio numbers in it?

Comment: @tobi_s, It was clear for me but maybe it was not for OP: you mentioned using `uint64_t` when the value typed in `std::cin` in the question was `100`, i.e. just that was higher than the capabilities of `uint64_t`.

Comment: @Pepjin Kramer yup, unless there's another one

Comment: @Atmo ah, yeah, I see why that may be confusing, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of both positive and negative numbers in your Fibonacci series is due to integer overflow.

When an integer overflows, its value wraps around. In the case of signed integers, which typically use two's complement representation, when the value exceeds the maximum positive value representable by the data type, it "wraps around" to the most negative value and continues decreasing. This explains why you're seeing negative values after reaching large positive ones.

For example, with a 32-bit signed integer:

- When you exceed the maximum positive value (2,147,483,647), the value
  wraps around to the most negative value (-2,147,483,648).
- It then continues decreasing towards more negative values until it
  reaches the minimum representable value (-2,147,483,648), after which
  it would overflow again and wrap around to the maximum positive
  value, creating a cycle of positive to negative values.

That's why in your Fibonacci series, after reaching large positive numbers that caused overflow, you start seeing negative values, and the sequence continues with alternating positive and negative numbers as the overflow wraps around.

Comment: No edits to the answer given?  You're a new contributor also.  Even veteran StackOverflow members have at least one edit to answers this lengthy.  This answer has all the earmarks of being AI generated.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the negative numbers's appearances are caused by data type value limit.
Let's consider the data type that you used in your code, `int`. The data type `int`'s value limit is `from -2^31 to 2^31-1`, equals to `from -2147483648 to 2147483647`.
When a value of type `int` overflows out of the range, it would be increased or decreased by multiple of the range span of the range, equals to `2^32`, in order to keep the value in the range of `int`.
For example, if you put `2147483648` into a variable of type `int`, the actual value in that variable is `2147483648-2^32`, equals to `-2147483648`.
Now let's consider the example the output:
`-285007387, -945834654, -1230842041, 2118290601, 887448560, -1289228135, -401779575, -1691007710`
The third number equals to the sum of the previous two numbers, `-285007387`and`-945834654`, equals to `(-285007387)+(-945834654)=-1230842041`, and that number is in the range, so the third number is `-1230842041`. The fourth number equals to `(-945834654)+(-1230842041)=-2176676695`, but that number is out of the range, so we increase it by `2^32`, so it becomes `(-2176676695)+2^32=2118290601`.

After calculating the example output, we can see that the output satisfy this law that ensure the value is in the type `int`'s value range. And because it is only to ensure it is in the range, there is actually no special reasons or methods to know it is positive or negative. In other words, there is no special reasons other than calculation that determine the positivity or negativity of the value.